# How can I increment a counter only for working hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a counter which increments +1 every minute. (Perfect will be around 70 value for one hour.)

But, the counter should start at 6 am and work until 8 pm (working hours), and Monday - Friday (working days). For weekends and outside working hours it should be paused, but it should show value counted. The next day it will continue from the last value.

Counter will stop at the end of the month, reset, 1st in month start again (if it's working day)

```
function startCounter() {
// Get the current date and time
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentDay = currentDate.getDay(); // 0: Sunday, 1: Monday, ..., 6: Saturday
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();

// Check if it's a weekend or outside working hours
var isWeekend = currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 6; // Sunday or Saturday
var isOutsideWorkingHours = currentHour < 6 || currentHour >= 20; // Before 6am or after 8pm

// If it's a weekend or outside working hours, pause the counter
if (isWeekend || isOutsideWorkingHours) {
  console.log('Counter paused.');
  return;
}

// Get the starting date for the counter
var startingDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1); // 1st of the current month

// Calculate the number of days since the starting date, excluding weekends
var daysSinceStart = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= currentDay; i++) {
  if (i !== 0 && i !== 6) {
    daysSinceStart++;
  }
}

// Calculate the initial value of the counter based on the number of previous days
var initialValue = daysSinceStart * 1440; // 1440 minutes in a day

// Initialize the counter with the initial value
var counter = initialValue;

// Increment the counter every minute
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  counter++;
  console.log('Counter:', counter);
}, 60000); // 60000 milliseconds = 1 minute

// Display the counter value on page refresh
console.log('Counter:', counter);
}

// Start the counter
startCounter();
```

What I'm missing here? Or whole logic must be updated?

Thank you!

Comment: `setInterval` isn't accurate enough for long-running timers, depending on what this counter is used for, you would probably be better off storing a timestamp and retroactively calculating the time difference when you need the `counter` value.

Comment: Well, it should just count, doesn't need to be accurate. Daily around 840 value, but the next day it should simply continue where it was paused the previous day. Or it's better to generate this code in php and create function, I need it for wordpress site.

Comment: Are you expecting to leave your page open 24/7?  What if the user refreshes/reloads the page?  What if the user needs to reboot?  What if the browser crashes?   Server-side your start time and use ajax to update how many minutes the browser has been open.

Comment: That's fair. No localStorage in code, but that part can be easily updated to store counted value. The main problem is, it doesn't work well with dates, not showing exact value for previous days. If user opens the website, it can count total of previous days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day!
First of all:
If you counting only for working hours, as you show, there are only 14 hours per day, not 24. There for you will add not 1440, but 840 minutes per day. But better is to make couple of vars (endHour and startHour) to be sure to count correctly everywhere.
If you want to show counting even if not a work time, but not counting do not return when checking.

Counting past days in your code dosn't work. You counting as there is only one week in month.

And You not count how many minutes passed from start of the day.
Counting by setInterval is not the best idea, but let it be here for test.
So, here is my code, I tested it for different start- and endHours and weekEndDays:

```
function startCounter() {
// Get the current date and time
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentDay = currentDate.getDay(); // 0: Sunday, 1: Monday, ..., 6: Saturday
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
var currentMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var currentDayOfMonth = currentDate.getDate();
// Check if it's a weekend or outside working hours
var weekEndDays = [0,6]; // weekend days - you can add or delete some days
var isWeekend = weekEndDays.indexOf(currentDay) > -1 ; // Is a weekend?
var startHour = 6;
var endHour = 20;
var isOutsideWorkingHours = currentHour < startHour || currentHour >= endHour; // Before startHour or after endHour


// Get the starting date for the counter
var startingDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1); // 1st of the current month

// Calculate the number of days since the starting date, excluding weekends and current day
var daysSinceStart = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < currentDayOfMonth; i++) {
    let checkDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), i);

    if (checkDate.getDay() !== 0 && checkDate.getDay() !== 6) {
        daysSinceStart++;
    }
}
var minutesSinceStartOfDay = 0;

// if today is working day, and work time is over, count it as fully passed day
if (!isWeekend && isOutsideWorkingHours && currentHour >= endHour){
    daysSinceStart++;
}
// If it's a weekend or outside working hours, show 'Counter paused.'
// else count minutes from start of a working day and show 'Counter starting...'

if (isWeekend || isOutsideWorkingHours) {
    console.log('Counter paused.');
    //return;
} else {
    minutesSinceStartOfDay = (currentHour - startHour)*60 + currentMinutes;
    console.log('Counter starting...');
}

// Calculate the initial value of the counter based on the number of previous days
 // (endHour-startHour)*60 minutes in a day
// Initialize the counter with the initial value
var counter = daysSinceStart * (endHour-startHour)*60 + minutesSinceStartOfDay;

// Increment the counter every minute
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (isWeekend || isOutsideWorkingHours) {
        console.log('Counter:', counter);
        return;
    }
    counter++;
    console.log('Counter:', counter);
}, 60000); // 60000 milliseconds = 1 minute

// Display the counter value on page refresh
console.log('Counter:', counter);
}

// Start the counter
startCounter();
```

Have fun!
Was interesting for me.

Comment: You can reload as often as need - it will count!